# Amp is not optimized for mobile devices

Tags: mobile, seo, amp-html

Can the valid amp page be not optimized for mobile devices?

I have the next problem.
I have an amp page
[image: I have an amp page]

Why do I have this label? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Yes, it is possible. That is why you got it.

Have a look, below is an amp url.

[image]

This is what it shows on mobile friendly test.

[image]

So, validating amp only validates its test amp tags' syntax, but does not automatically improves design. Design is at your end.

So, if a page is valid amp, does not imply it has good design, so, does not imply it is mobile friendly.
Also, for the sake of completeness, if a page is mobile friendly, does not imply is is valid amp page.

You can run mobile friendly test [here](https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly) and find the particular issues which is making it a non mobile friendly.
[image]

After you fix the issues listed in the test, you can re-run the test and if it show a green flag, you can submit it for the new design.[image]

Comment: This is the main problem. All my amp pages are mobile friendly. But But the label is still present. Have a look below

Comment: Then try re-submitting the test to google. Make sure you submit for the amp version and not the mobile version.